# magento2 override admin js file function

Tags: magento2, admin, orders

I want to override function `setShippingMethod()` to my module js `vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\web\order\create\scripts.js`

here is a function

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    "mage/translate",
    "prototype",
    "Magento_Catalog/catalog/product/composite/configure",
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async'
], function(jQuery, confirm, alert){

    window.AdminOrder = new Class.create();

    AdminOrder.prototype = {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        setShippingMethod : function(method){
            var data = {};
            data['order[shipping_method]'] = method;
            console.log(method);
            this.loadArea(['shipping_method', 'totals', 'billing_method'], true, data);
            /*if(method=='dpd_relay_common'){
                jQuery( "#click-me" ).trigger( "click" );

            }*/
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To overide that things, you need to do this things.

1. Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\requirejs-config.js add this:

   ```
   var config = {
     map: {
       '*': {
           'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts':'Vendor_Extension/order/create/scripts'
       }
     }
   };
   ```
2. Then create the file `Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\web\order\create\scripts.js` with your content.

Comment: I want to override only one function instead file, this function declared with some different syntax, that's why I'm asking

Comment: single function is not possible, but in this way when you overide this one, you need to modify only that function, rest of the things you need to take as it is.